# Python Tkinter MenuButton

Tags: python-2.7, drop-down-menu, menu, tkinter

I am trying to create a beginner program with Tkinter that will simulate NFL games. I am getting stuck while creating my 'scoreboard' in with Tkinter. The below code brings up part of the scoreboard in one window and two menu buttons with the teams in another window. Why are these on separate windows? I am trying to get the two menu buttons to show up next to 'Away Team' and 'Home Team' so the user can select which team they would like. Not worried about the calc just yet, just trying to get the GUI up and running first. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
from Tkinter import *
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk

teams = ['Arizona Cardinals','Atlanta Falcons','Baltimore Ravens', 
'Buffalo Bills','Carolina Panthers','Chicago Bears','Cincinnati Bengals',
'Cleveland Browns','Dallas Cowboys','Denver Broncos','Detroit Lions',
'Green Bay Packers','Houston Texans','Indianapolis Colts','Jacksonville Jaguars',
'Kansas City Chiefs','Miami Dolphins','Minnesota Vikings','New England Patriots',
'New Orleans Saints','New York Giants','New York Jets','Oakland Raiders','Philadelphia Eagles','Pittsburgh Steelers','San Diego Chargers','San Francisco 49ers',
'Seattle Seahawks','St. Louis Rams','Tampa Bay Buccaneers','Tennessee Titans',
'Washington Redskins']

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.grid()

        global root
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (330, 80, 200, 150))
        root.title("tk.Optionmenu as combobox")

        global var
        var = tk.StringVar(root)
        var.set('Arizona Cardinals')

        sf = "value is %s" % var.get()
        root.title(sf)

        master.title("NFL Simulator")

        self.lblTeamA = Label(self.frame,text = "Away Team")
        self.lblTeamA.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "ew")
        self.txtTeamA = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, *teams)
        self.txtTeamA.pack(side='right', padx=10, pady=10)
        self.txtTeamA.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        self.lblTeamB = Label(self.frame,text = "Home Team")
        self.lblTeamB.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "ew")
        self.txtTeamB = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, *teams)
        self.txtTeamB.pack(side='right', padx=10, pady=10)
        self.txtTeamB.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        self.btnCalc = Button(self.frame,text = "Simulate Game",command = self.calc)
        self.btnCalc.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

        self.lblScoreAPrompt = Label(self.frame,text = "Away Team Score")
        self.lblScoreAPrompt.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = "ew")
        self.lblScoreA = Label(self.frame, bg = "white", anchor = "w")
        self.lblScoreA.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = "ew")

        self.lblScoreBPrompt = Label(self.frame,text = "Home Team Score")
        self.lblScoreBPrompt.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = "ew")
        self.lblScoreB = Label(self.frame, bg = "white", anchor = "w")
        self.lblScoreB.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = "ew")

    def calc(self):
        TeamA = int(self.txtTeamA.get())
        TeamB = int(self.txtTeamB.get())

        self.lblTeamA["text"] = random.randint(3,45)
        self.lblTeamB["text"] = random.randint(3,45)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your root is the master. I.e.:

```
global root
root = master
```

And `OptionMenu` should be attached to the same frame as other labels in order to show them beside each other:

```
self.txtTeamA = tk.OptionMenu(self.frame, var, *teams)
```

---

"How can I make them independent of each other?"

In simple terms, you should be using two different variables to store the selected option. In your code, they're both associated with `var`, so on changing one `OptionMenu` changes `var` which changes the other `OptionMenu`.

```
varA = tk.StringVar(root)
varA.set('Arizona Cardinals')

varB = tk.StringVar(root)
varB.set('Baltimore Ravens')

self.txtTeamA = tk.OptionMenu(root, varA, *teams)

self.txtTeamB = tk.OptionMenu(root, varB, *teams)
```

Comment: @russherm I have edited my answer to show how to make them independent.